# Dynamic creating .xlsx file and use it as a data provider / supplier in testNg selenium framework

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

Is there a way / test workflow --  if i want to read String contents from the gui and put it in a ArrayList and then write it to an .xlsx file and use this file as a data provider. If yes, can i get the @testNG annotation workflow of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the below approach. I have added the resources below to help you with code and dependencies as well.

1. Create a method - `storeDataFromGUI()`
   Get the data that you want to enter from your GUI using standard selenium methods `getText()` and store it in a collection.
2. Add Apache POI in your dependencies(if you are using maven) -
   To Read/Write data into Excel file you can use Apache POI. Just add the dependencies in your maven project and that's it. You can then refer to the sample code available online and modify it based on your needs.
3. Create two methods using Apache POI a. `writingDataInExcel()` b. `readingDataFromExcel()`
4. In TestNG, in `@beforeMethod` annotation call the above methods as
   `storeDataFromGUI()` ->`writingDataInExcel()`
5. In your `@DataProvider` annotation, call `readingDataFromExcel()` method to pass the data entered in Excel.

Resources:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-data-excel-file-using-apache-poi/
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi

Comment: Thank you very much for your response i will give it a shot and let you know. Thanks again!